# Maintain position of fixed element in boxed layout, responsive design

Tags: css, css-position, fluid-layout

first time asker here.

I have a boxed layout (max width 1014px) made of up 2 columns.

The right column has a width of 400px and scrolls.

The left column needs to be fixed to the top left (not scroll) of the left column, occupy the remaining available width of the "box" and remain within the "Box" at larger screen sizes.

At smaller than 1024px screen sizes only the left column should sacrifice width in a fluid style while the right column maintains its width.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll do what you're looking for.

Basically, a fixed-left div with fluid layout, but at 1024px has a breakpoint that turns it into a fixed-width fixed div that's centered via left-margin hack.

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="left-col">
        left
    </div>
    <div class="right-col">
        right
    </div>
</div>
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.box {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.right-col {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width: 400px;
}
.left-col {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 400px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .left-col {
        width: 624px;
        left: -512px;
        right: initial;
        margin-left: 50%;
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Yes that did it alright. Thank you very much indeed.